# Accessing extern NSString from Objective-C in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa

I have an extern as NSString in Objective-c and wanted to see if it can be accessed from Swift? And if so how would it get accessed.

Let's say the extern is as following:

```
extern NSString *_Nonnull const test;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily test this thing

Like you have a file **const.h** where you have placed that extern
Now import const.h in bridging header, if that extern is just a string or number or int or something like that it will easily be accessible

Like

**Const.h**

```
extern NSString * const test = “testing”;
```

**Bridging_header.h**

```
#import “const.h”
```

**SwiftTest.swift**
....

```
Print(test)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use it in `Swift` as global constant `test`, similar to `let test = "message"` outside class/struct scope